# Regex to split on uppercase but not if preceded by space?

Tags: python, regex, split

In Python is there any way of doing the following? I have a string like `"Trip HopDowntempoSynth-pop"` and I am able to split on the uppercase character, but what I want is to split on uppercase unless preceded by a space.

I tried adding a `!` to:

```
print (re.findall(r'[A-Z](?:A-Z*(?![a-z])|[a-z]*)',line))
```

with no difference in where I placed the addition.

Comment: Can you add your desired output?

Comment: Findall and split are different things. It also seems like you want to split on spaces followed by uppercase, not uppercase. Can you give an example input and output? You may want a lookahead like: `tweets_file = open('tweets.txt', "r"))` which gives `['aaa', 'BcccDeee qqqq 9.', 'Fggg', 'HiiiJeee']`

Comment: Your example, split by uppercase not preceded by space is `re.split("(?<! )[A-Z]", "Trip HopDowntempoSynth-pop")` which results in `['', 'rip Hop', 'owntempo', 'ynth-pop']`. We want several example inputs and outputs so we can figure out the various conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this?

```
re.split('\s+(?=[A-Z])', "Trip HopDowntempoSynth-pop")
# ['Trip', 'HopDowntempoSynth-pop']
```

---

Or the opposite:

```
pattern = re.compile('[A-Z][^A-Z\s]+(?:\s+\S[^A-Z\s]*)*')

pattern.findall("Trip HopDowntempoSynth-pop")
# ['Trip Hop', 'Downtempo', 'Synth-pop']

pattern.findall("Trip Hop HHopDowntempoSynth-pop")
#['Trip Hop H', 'Hop', 'Downtempo', 'Synth-pop']
```

Comment: I believe they want the opposite; your example is splitting on only those uppercase characters that are preceded by a space. OP Wants to split on all uppercase characters NOT preceded by a space

Comment: @Hamms Yeah I added the opposite too.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially roundabout, but achieved what I think you're looking for with a combination of iterating through re.findall and using re.sub to replace matches with a placeholder character that is then split...

```
import re
s = "Trip HopDowntempoSynth-pop"

pattern = re.compile("[a-z][A-Z]")

matches = re.findall(pattern, s)

for match in matches:
    match_replacer = match[0] + '|' + match[1]
    s = s.replace(match, match_replacer)


s.split('|')
```

which gives the output

```
['Trip Hop', 'Downtempo', 'Synth-pop']
```

Comment: actually this assumes capital letters must be preceded by a lowercase letter, might alternatively want to use `pattern = re.compile("[^\s][A-Z]")`

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a regex, but it is easy enough to fit your problem.

```
s = "Trip HopDowntempoSynth-pop"

arr = []
word = s[0]
for i in range(1, len(s)):
    if s[i].isupper():
        if s[i - 1] == " ":
            word += s[i]
        else:
            arr.append(word)
            word = s[i]
    else:
        word += s[i]
arr.append(word)

print(arr)
```

It prints out an array that looks like this:

**['Trip Hop', 'Downtempo', 'Synth-pop']**